# Счетчик на Delphi: продолжение счета

Tags: delphi

Работает так, щелкаю по кнопке, в едите показано сколько раз, оно это сохраняет в файл, после закрытия программы, когда вхожу заново, оно сохраняет то значение, но когда заново нажимаю на кнопку, счетчик обнуляется, как сделать продолжение счета?

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
   type
  TData = record
    Number: Integer;

  end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;
      i:integer;
       Data: TData;
  F: File of TData;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
type
  TData = record
    Number: Integer;
  end;
var
Data: TData;
  F: File of TData;
begin

  edit1.Text:=IntToStr(i);
  i:=i+1;
  AssignFile(F, 'C:\Data.dat');
  Reset(F);

  Data.Number := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
  Write(F, Data);
  CloseFile(F);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
AssignFile(F, 'C:\Data.dat');
  Reset(F);

  Read(F, Data);
  Edit1.Text := IntToStr(Data.Number);
  CloseFile(F);
end;

end.
```

Comment: @друг человека Если Вы хотите принять ответ, просто кликните по галочке под ладошкой вниз слева от ответа.

Answer (score 2):

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
AssignFile(F, 'C:\Data.dat');
  Reset(F);

  Read(F, Data);
  **i:=Data.Number;**
  Edit1.Text := IntToStr(Data.Number);
  CloseFile(F);
end;
```

Скорее всего так вот. присвоить значение переменной **i**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
type
  TData = record
    Number: Integer;
  end;
var
Data: TData;
  F: File of TData;
begin

  edit1.Text:=IntToStr(i);
  i:=i+1;
  AssignFile(F, 'C:\Data.dat');
  Reset(F);

  Data.Number := i;//зачем делать перевод из текста в число, ведь у тебя это число уже есть!
  Write(F, Data);
  CloseFile(F);
end;
```

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло)))

Comment: я еще дополнил ответ исправь.

Привыкай не делать лишних телодвижений когда данные у тебя уже есть.

и если помогло плюсик, к ответу не забываем ставить

Comment: для плюсика мне надо 15 баллов!

Comment: копи баллы :)

Comment: второй вариант обнуляет при нажатии кнопки!

Comment: не должен обнулять, это ведь тоже самое число и ты с ним ничего не делаешь просто записываешь в файл.
<br>
Data.Number := i; - это не будет тебе ничего обнулять.
<br>
i:=i+1; замени на inc(i); запись проще, разбираться потом тоже проще.
<br>
у тебя уже 19 уважухи :)

Comment: да но то было в форме в первый раз, а то на кнопке!

Comment: TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

это при нажатии на кнопку ты берешь значение и запихиваешь его в файл.
<pre><code>
edit1.Text:=IntToStr(i);
  i:=i+1;
  AssignFile(F, 'C:\Data.dat');
  Reset(F);

  Data.Number := i;
  Write(F, Data);
  CloseFile(F);
</code></pre>
в файл записывается число, которое чуть выше было инкрементировано на 1.

Answer (score 1):

Будьте проще :)

```
// глобальные
var
  Counter: integer;
const
  FILENAME_COUNTER = 'MyCounter.txt';

...

procedure LoadCounter;
var
  f: file of integer;
begin
  if FileExists(FILENAME_COUNTER) then
  begin
    AssignFile(f, FILENAME_COUNTER);
    Reset(f);
    Read(f, Counter);
    CloseFile(f);
  end else
    Counter := 0;
end;

procedure SaveCounter;
var
  f: file of integer;
begin
  AssignFile(f, FILENAME_COUNTER);
  Rewrite(f);
  Write(f, Counter);
  CloseFile(f);
end;

...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LoadCounter;
  Edit1.Text := IntToStr(Counter);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SaveCounter;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inc(Counter);
  Edit1.Text := IntToStr(Counter);
end;
```

Comment: как вариант кстати :)

Comment: так даже лучше

Comment: Со временем придет ;)